# Tshark filter protocol FIX

Tags: windows, wireshark

Can someone help me? 
I can not save file.

```
C:\Program Files\Wireshark>Tshark -i rpcap://[172.16.254.6]/\Device\NPF_{CF9CFF4
6-79FF-4A97-802A-F6CEF5896D29} -Y fix -w C:\ts.pcap
tshark: Display filters aren't supported when capturing and saving the captured
packets.
```

Answer (score 3):

As the message indicates, "`tshark: Display filters aren't supported when capturing and saving the captured packets.`", so you'll have to remove the display filter.  In other words, remove `-Y fix` and it should work, although you'll be capturing all traffic without some sort of filter, so that's probably not what you want.

If you want to limit the packets that are captured, then you need to use a capture filter, not a display filter, and that is done via the `-f` option.  As mentioned on [this](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/29829/fix-protocol-capturing) question over at the Wireshark Q&A site, a command such as follows may be useful to you:

```
C:\Program Files\Wireshark>Tshark -i rpcap://[172.16.254.6]/\Device\NPF_{CF9CFF46-79FF-4A97-802A-F6CEF5896D29} -f "tcp[20:4]=0x383D4649 and tcp[24:1]=0x58" -w C:\ts.pcap
```